# Assuming role in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm wondering if I run a AWS client application on my local machine can it use the roles the same way an EC2 instance is configured to use the role?  My understanding is that AWS Roles are only configurable/applicable for services running in AWS.  Roles cannot be used in local development environment.  But I also see "assume role" api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use the assume role API which will provide you with temporary AWS access and secret key associated with the role's permissions.  Note that before you are able to assume a role, the role's trust policy must permit you to do so, by listing your IAM user ARN in the trust policy, for example.

Basically internally, this is what happens when an EC2 instance is assigned a role, an STS call is made (numerous times as the credentials are periodically refreshed) to return a set of temporary credentials that can be used.

Here is [one example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/), and there are many available online.

Comment: Thank for you the explanation.